# Skorokhod Representation: $|X_n(t) - X_n(s)| \leq |t-s| \Rightarrow |X(t) - X(s)| \leq |t-s|$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, weak-convergence

While working out problems from the Chapter on Skorokhod Representation from "Stochastic processes" by Richard Bass, Chapter 32, I came across this problem:

**Question:**

Suppose $X_n$ converges weakly to $X$ and each $X_n$ has the property that with probability $1$,
$$|X_n(t) - X_n(s)| \leq |t-s|, \quad s,t\leq 1$$

Prove that with probability $1$,
$$|X(t) - X(s)| \leq |t-s|, \quad s,t\leq 1$$

**My Doubts and thoughts:**

1. The condition $s,t\leq 1$ probably should be $|s|,|t|\leq 1$.
2. The condition indicates that the sample paths of $X_n$ are continuous (moreover Lipschitz). However as the space $C[0,1]$ is in the next chapter, I won't be using theorems from there.
3. When talking about weak convergence of stochastic processes in general, does $X_n(t)\to^w X(t)$ mean for every $t$, $X_n(t)$ converges weakly to $X(t)$? Since I am comfortable only with the random variable versions, kindly hint to a good reference for this.
4. I'm not sure how to apply Skorokhod theorem here. I thought of considering $\hat{X_n}$, but I am not sure if the property mentioned above for $X_n$ holds here. After all, $X_n =^d \hat{X_n}$.
5. It somewhat feels like a limit has been taken on LHS. Since we only have weak convergence, I'm tempted to take the Skorokhod representation Theorem path.

I'd appreciate it if someone could clarify 3) and 4). Any relevant hints are also welcome.

**Edit:** 
Skorokhod Theorem:

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a complete separable metric space, $\Omega = [0,1]$, $\mathcal{B}$ the Borel Sigma algebra on $[0,1]$ and $\hat{\mathbb{P}}$ the Lebesgue measure on $\Omega$. Let $\mathbb{P}_n \to^w \mathbb{P}$, where $\mathbb{P_n},\mathbb{P}$ are probability measures on $\mathcal{S}$. Then $\exists$ random variables $X_n$ and $X$ mapping $\Omega$ to $\mathcal{S}$ with law $\mathbb{P}$ such that $X_n \to X$ a.s.

Equivalently, if $X_n \to^w X$, there exist random variables $\hat{X_n}$ and $\hat{X}$ mapping $\Omega$ to $\mathcal{S}$ with laws equal to $X_n$ and $X$ resp. such that $\hat{X_n} \to \hat{X}$ a.s.

Comment: I've edited the post. It's been stated now.

Comment: Thanks you. Here, I think the problem is to know on which space the processes $X_n(t,\cdot)$ live. If it's the space of continuous functions on the unit interval, then it will work (since $\widehat{X_n}$ will still satisfy Lipschitz property).

Comment: Thank you Davide. Unfortunately this is all that is given.

Comment: It seems strange that you cannot use the space of continuous functions and the statement of the Skorokhod theorem involves a separable complete metric space. And  "weak convergence", as your point 3. asks, involves a structure of topological space. Does the author mention it?

Comment: Sadly No. As for the weak convergence part, I googled "weak convergence stochastic processes" and found an article by Monroe Donsker http://www.mscand.dk/article.php?id=1591 which explained that bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe what the author had in mind is the following: let $I:=\mathbb Q\cap [0,1]$ and $X:=\mathbb R^I$ endowed a natural metric ($\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}2^{-n}\min\{1,|x_n-y_n|\}=:d(x,y)$ for $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$, then use a bijection between $I$ and $\mathbb N$). We have a structure of separable complete normed space.

Using Skorokhod representation theorem, we can assert that there is $\Omega'\subset\Omega$ of probability one such that for each $s,t\in I$ and $\omega\in\Omega'$, we have 
$$|X(s,\omega)-X(t,\omega)|\leqslant |s-t|.$$
From this, we can deduce the result for $s,t\in [0,1]$.